# Is it correct? Linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm new in linear algebra and I'm trying to solve this exercise but I'm stuck with the conclusion.

> Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers. Show that the following vectors $(1,a,a^{2}), (1,b,b^{2}),(1,c,c^{2}) \in \mathbb{R^{3}}$ are linearly independent if and only if $a \neq b$, $a \neq c$ and $b \neq c$.

My try.

$\longrightarrow$

Let $\alpha , \beta , \gamma$ be scalars so that

$$ \alpha (1,a,a^{2}) + \beta (1,b,b^{2}) + \gamma (1,c,c^{2})=(0,0,0)$$

Now we have the following equations
\begin{aligned}
&\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 0 && (1)\\
&\alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c=0 && (2) \\
&\alpha a^{2} + \beta b^{2} + \gamma c^{2} = 0 && (3)
\end{aligned}

Solving for equation 1, we have

$\alpha = - \beta - \gamma$

Substituting this last equation in 2

$a(-\beta - \gamma) + \beta b + \gamma c = 0$

$-a\beta - a\gamma + \beta b + \gamma c = 0$

$\beta (-a+b) + \gamma (-a+c) = 0$

Now I don't know how to finish the proof. If someone could give me a hint, I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Are you allowed to use determinants to solve the problem?

Comment: I can't use determiners yet, as I haven't read about it yet.

(I am studying linear algebra by my self)

Answer (score 1):

Those three vectors are independent if and only if (iff) equations (1,2,3) only have the zero solution iff the determinant of the coefficients matrix is not zero.

Observe that $\det\begin{bmatrix}1,&1,&1\\a,&b,&c\\a^2,&b^2,&c^2\end{bmatrix}=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)$, then the conclusion is obvious.

This kind of determinant is called Vandermonde determinant. Google it.

Comment: This is probably too good of an answer for the question in my opinion

Comment: Thaks,  but I can't use determiners yet

Answer (score 1):

Without determinants, you can look at the matrix of the system and perform Gaussian elimination:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
a & b & c \\
a^2 & b^2 & c^2
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & b-a & c-a \\
0 & b^2-a^2 & c^2-a^2
\end{bmatrix}
&& \begin{aligned} R_2 &\gets R_2-aR_1 \\ R_3&\gets R_3-a^2R_1\end{aligned}
\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & b-a & c-a \\
0 & 0 & (c-a)(c-b)
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3 \gets R_3-(b+a)R_2
\end{align}
If $a=b$ or $a=c$ or $b=c$, we get rank at most $2$.

Comment: thanks, it was a better option for gaussian elimination to solve the system of equations.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much there, that $$\beta(b-a)+\gamma(c-a)=0$$ is correct. Now, linear independence happens when $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$ is *forced* by the vectors.

When $a=b$ or $a=c$ is true, this equation becomes $\beta\cdot 0+ \gamma(c-a) =0$ or $\beta(b-a)+\gamma\cdot0=0$, with $\alpha=-(\beta+\gamma)$.

In the first case, we can pick $\gamma=0$ and $\beta$ can be anything we want to get zero, so these are linearly independent. The same works for the second case. Also, if you used $\gamma=-(\alpha+\beta)$, you'd also see that $b=c$ can't be true either.

Hence, for the vectors to be linearly independent, $a=b, a=c$ and $b=c$ must be false.

From the third equation (of squares) we have that:

$$\beta(b^2-a^2)+\gamma(c^2-a^2)=0$$
Expand by DOTS for $$\beta(b-a)(b+a)+\gamma(c-a)(c+a)=0$$

and here again, only $a=b=c$ gives us free choice on $\beta$ and $\gamma$. At first glance, it looks like $-a=b=c$ would give us free choice, but by using $\gamma=-(\alpha+\beta)$ instead, you would get $-a=b, -b=c, -c=a$, which are together completely impossible. Here again, wherever $a=b=c$ is false, the vectors are linearly independent as $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$ is forced.

Comment: thanks, i was manipulate β (b − a) + γ (c − a) = 0 incorrectly. so I got confused when i wanted to get new information